# Can I build a service throttle in EC2 infront of the elastic load balancer?

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mule

I have an autoscaled web/app tier behind an Elastic Load Balancer in EC2.  I'd like to set-up a throttle for my REST web services to enforce a per-second transaction limit.  I'd like to enforce it based on the service being called and some proprietary http header information passed in on the request.  I was thinking about standing up a mule server to throttle the incoming requests then forward them to the ELB or return a http 503, but I don't know how difficult this would be to build and test, or if it would work at all.

Is there anyway I can set-up something infront of my ELB to throttle incoming requests?  Is there a better way to perform web service throttling in EC2?

Comment: Not a curveball, but have you considered using a service like Apigee for this?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but I'm not clear on how switching to Apigee solves my service throttling problem in EC2.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Throttling is one of the feature Apigee is supposed to offer. I'm not suggesting a switch though, just using them as a frontal proxy for your services.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure throttling on EC2, ELB doesn't provide ability to limit request rate.

Comment: Yes, I understand the ELB does not provide that capability.  I was asking about setting up a throttle elsewhere (likely EC2) that calls the ELB if the throttle quota is not met.  The problem is I don't know if you can setup a server to act in this manner:  return the result of the REST service called without repackaging the response or return 503.

Comment: Well, CloudWatch allows to handle ELB metrics: http://harish11g.blogspot.com/2012/02/cloudwatch-elastic-load-balancing.html. Maybe you need autoscalling when request rate exceed your ec2 capacity?